# Webpack Less-Loader with Style-Loader not injecting <style> tag

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, less-loader

I'm trying to have our .less files picked up by `less-loader`, then by `css-loader`, and finally injected into the HTML file by `style-loader`, as per the [Less Loader docs.](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader)

I am not getting any errors or warnings, but the styles are not injected or present in any way.

My webpack config is as follows, under module.rules[]...:

```
{
     test: /\.css$/,
         use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
     },
     {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
                loader: "less-loader",
                // options: {
                //     paths: [
                //         path.resolve(__dirname, '../less')
                //     ]
                // } // compiles Less to CSS
       }]
    },
}
```

My `resolve` is as follows

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.less'],
    alias: {
        '@': resolve('public/js'),
    },
    modules: ['less', 'node_modules']
},
```

I have also tried, under `modules`, `path.resolve(__dirname, '../less')`

My directory structure is

`project/build/webpack.config.js`

`project/less/*.less` (less files)

I have also tried with the commented "options" above uncommented, to point directly at the less directory, as per the less-loader docs.

What am I missing to have these less styles compiled to CSS and injected as a style tag?

I included the .css test because I'm curious if maybe there's some sort of conflict happening there. It's being used to inject the bootstrap css file from node_modules, which is working properly.

(I tried to keep the code brief and only including relevant portions - happy to provide more)

Comment: are you calling your `.less` files in your `.js` files?

Comment: Just the bootstrap ones, do I need to for the .less ones? I thought that was the point of style-loader? What would I even point to?

Comment: I mean you need to import them `import './main.less'` in your `.js` files, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Damn, this brave new world of modules is very different than what I'm used to! After importing the less files (and making sure the less files import the other less files with the variables they use), it works. Do you want to submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: haha yeah I understand, I have the exact same confusion than you but it's very nice once you get used to it and sure I'll submit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your `.less` files in your `.js` files in this way webpack loader will find them and make it work.

[Here](https://github.com/arkgast/react-firebase-starter/tree/0457a8a9ba6078a5ee2df9bcd0b838878ba56ffb) I have a repo with some configuration and I think it will help you with some issues that you'll face later. (Yeah it becomes a little bit wilder)

Regards.