# Module not found after adding lang="less" to style tag in component.vue

Tags: vuejs2, less, quasar-framework

My question is similar to this one but I do not understand the answer there:
[Webpack Less-Loader with Style-Loader not injecting <style> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040994/webpack-less-loader-with-style-loader-not-injecting-style-tag/56166087#56166087)

I don't have the "reputation" to comment, so I will ask a new question.

I do not want to include my .less fine in my .js, I simply want to use LessCSS notation in the  tag in my layout, template, page and components.

I have installed the less loader:
$npm install --save-dev less-loader

I have added the following to my quasar.conf.js file:

```
 extendWebpack (cfg) {
/* EXISTING
   cfg.module.rules.push({
     enforce: 'pre',
     test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
     loader: 'eslint-loader',
     exclude: /node_modules/
   })
*/
// NEW
   cfg.module.rules.push({
     test: /\.less$/,
     use: [
       'vue-style-loader',
       'css-loader',
       'less-loader'
     ]
   })
 }
```

And as soon as I add " lang='less'" to my style tag of my component (LoadingOverlay.vue):

```html
<style lang="less">
</style>
```

I get the following error when running quasar dev:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                  12:02:54
 error  in ./src/components/global/LoadingOverlay.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=less&

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


// load the styles
var content = require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!../../../node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./LoadingOverlay.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=less&");
          ^
Unrecognised input
      in C:\wamp\www\plenty-mobile\src\components\global\LoadingOverlay.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=less& (line 4, column 12)
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--9-oneOf-2-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--9-oneOf-2-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-2-2!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-2-3!./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/global/LoadingOverlay.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=less& 4:14-539 14:3-18:5 15:22-547
 @ ./src/components/global/LoadingOverlay.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=less&
 @ ./src/components/global/LoadingOverlay.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/layouts/default.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/layouts/default.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/layouts/default.vue
 @ ./src/router/routes.js
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./.quasar/app.js
 @ ./.quasar/client-entry.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./.quasar/client-entry.js
```

Any help very much appreciated - thanks

I have followed the docs and tried the above but am limited as I am pretty new to quasar framework and vueJS

I simply expect to be able to use lessCSS notation in my  tags in templates, layouts, pages and components